jenkins: create new node from my NestJS application
I am trying to create a node from my NestJS application using api request, and got error code 400 "Bad Request"
this is my code:
async createNode(agentName: string, url: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const data = {
        name: agentName,
        type: 'hudson.slaves.DumbSlave',
        json: JSON.stringify({
          name: agentName,
          nodeDescription: '',
          numExecutors: 1,
          remoteFS: 'C:\\Jenkins',
          labelString: '',
          mode: 'EXCLUSIVE',
          retentionStrategy: {
            'stapler-class': 'hudson.slaves.RetentionStrategy$Always',
          },
          launcher: {
            'stapler-class': 'hudson.slaves.JNLPLauncher',
          },
          nodeProperties: {
            'stapler-class-bag': 'true',
          },
        }),
      };
      const response = await this.axiosInstance.post(
        `${url}/computer/doCreateItem?name=${agentName}&type=hudson.slaves.DumbSlave`,
        data,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        },
      );
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw new HttpException(
          `Failed to create node: ${response.statusText}`,
          HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw new HttpException(
        `Failed to create node: ${error}`,
        HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
      );
    }
  }

what am i doing wrong?
can find documentation about it

URLSearchParams converts data into x-www-form-urlencoded format but you are using json so to convert it into json you need to set header content type as json explicitly . i.e 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
replace your response const line with below code .
const response = await this.axiosInstance.post(
  `${url}/computer/doCreateItem?name=${agentName}&type=hudson.slaves.DumbSlave`,
  data,
  {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    },
  },
);


thanks for helping
my api request fail on same error even when i am adding the header "'Content-Type': 'application/json',"
i think that i am missing some required parameter in my body
